# How to replace entire dir to destination dir and sub-dirs?

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

Just want to ask, how can I replace files in destination directory and subdirectories with the same files from source? Say I want to replace file "X" in destination directory or subdirectory with file "X" from source directory, the script must go through all directories and subdirectories to find file "X" and replace it

```
Example 

Source:        "C:\MyPics\New\*.*"
Destination:   "C:\MyPics\All\A\*.*"
               "C:\MyPics\All\B\1\*.*"
               "C:\MyPics\All\B\2\*.*"
               "C:\MyPics\All\C\*.*"
```

Do you have any suggestions to accomplish this?

Hope to hear from you soon.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to search for destination directories first or do you know all of their paths?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but I think I've got the code correct.

If you are looking to replace with a single file from your source, then

```
@echo off
set "src=C:\MyPics\New\"
set "dst=C:\MyPics\All\"
set "file=X"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "%dst%%file%"') do copy /y "%src%%file%" "%%F"
```

If you are looking to replace with all files from source, then

```
@echo off
set "src=C:\MyPics\New\*"
set "dst=C:\MyPics\All\"
for %%S in ("%src%") do (
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "%dst%%%~nxF"') do copy /y "%%S" "%%F"
)
```

You could change the mask in the `src` definition to be more specific then `*`